# Internet Connection Super Slow on Mac but not on iPhone on the same network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mac, connection, iphone

I have a wireless home network with 2 clients - My mac, and my iPhone.

Over the past month, I have noticed that the internet speed on my mac is really slow. I get 100kbps on my 512kbps (third world country etc.) connection on my mac, but on my iPhone, the speed is 560kbps.

The tests are done with speedtest.net on both the devices.

When the test is done on one device, the other device's internet connection is cut.

I have tried changing the DNS of the mac connection to Google DNS with no success.

How can I debug this?

Comment: Is it your INTERNET speed or NETWORK speed? Huge difference? Step #1 is use an Ethernet cable and see if that makes a difference. If it does, your problem has nothing to do with your internet connection. If not, we'll go from there.

Comment: I prefer speedOfme http://speedof.me for browser based testing.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possible reasons.

The stand-out one being how well the devices can "hear" the WIFI.  The ideal is to use an ethernet cable where possible, but failing which, move the devices closer together so they can hear each other better.

Another issue could be software (or the software stack).  Try an alternative browser - if its faster, go into your preferred browser and delete your histories and caches.

Another issue could be "other software or devices".  It is possible that other software is interfering with your could be interfering with your device. Try (temporarily) changing your WIFI AP password to ensure your device is the only one that can talk to the router and see if things pick up.  If they do, then its a matter of tracking down who/what is using the bandwidth normally.

Depending on your ISP and router, see if you can get advice on your utilisation - particularly when you do not think you are utilising the device.